# purchaseToken of consumable products in android in-app purchasing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-billing

I have read quite a few posts on the in app purchasing in android but I still have a few doubts:

1. When an item gets consumed can we still get the details (purchaseToken etc) from google play? If yes, how? Any link to documentation regarding this?
2. Is purchaseToken unique for each new purchase that anyone makes? I want my app to distinguish purchases per device and I know purchase token is (user + product) unique. If I use purchaseToken to make sure that no duplicate devices get the item based on a purchaseToken that already exists, will it be possible?
   Or will it have to be deviceId+purchaseToken to make sure that only authentic devices get the item?
3. Is orderId unique?

Thanks in advance for your help. Please let me know in case I am not being clear.